# IsRequired applied to column with default value

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following SQL table:

```
create table dbo.Post (
  Id int identity not null,
  Content nvarchar (max) not null,
  Title nvarchar (200) not null,
  Created datetime not null
    constraint DF_Post_Created default getutcdate()
)
```

So I set a default value for Created and set it to not null.

How should Entity Framework configuration be? Something like:

```
Property(x => x.Created).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

**Do I need to add IsRequired?** I am not sure if IsRequired means that EF should require a value for Created or if Created is required on the database.

Answer (score 1):

`IsRequired` would set the column to be `NOT NULL` in sql if the database were generated by EF.

Having a default value means if a value isn't specified *when inserting a record*, the default value will be used.

If you don't want to allow nulls in the column, the column should be NOT NULL and the entity property should be set `IsRequired`.

Comment: So when you have Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) IsRquired is also needed because it is NotNull ... And the same happens with HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) if there is a default value defined and not null. Is this right?

Comment: `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` will prevent EF from setting any value at all to the field, including null, so `IsRequired` is incompatible with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well,EF doesn't have yet a good support for *default values*. Apparently this is something that [EF 7](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first) is going to have a better support due to the community has been [requesting](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/44) this some time ago.

I have already mapped your table using [EF Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) and the configuration class that was generated was this:

```
public class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Content)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Posts");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Content).HasColumnName("Content");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");
    }
}
```

As you can see the `Created` column was not mapped as required, and if you don't set that property, EF will going to throw an exception because that column will attempt to update with `default(DateTime)` wich is `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` and the type of that column is `datetime` (more details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386360/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o)).Even if you change the type of that column to `datetime2`, you are not going to have the behavior that you are expecting.

If you want a property with a default value, you could resolve that problem setting the property in the entity's contructor:

```
public class Post
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [Required]
   public DateTime Created{get;set;}
   public Post()
   {
      Created=DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```