# How to compare datetime2 with datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2014, datetime2

I need compare property datetime2 that one database with property datetime that other database because I don't find method for convert datetime to datetime2.

I test this sentence:

```
select CAST(FechaAlta AS datetime) from tutors
```

but return this error message:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393350/1821329

Answer (score 4):

The `datetime2` data type has a wider range than `datetime` - `datetime2` can hold any date between `0001-01-01` and `9999-12-31`, whereas `datetime` starts at `01/01/1753` (there are obscure reasons for this involving the 4th Earl of Chesterfield that are too arcane to go into at this juncture).

If you want to convert your datetime2 to a datetime, you have to handle the out-of-range values, for instance:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FechaAlta < '1753-01-01' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(FechaAlta AS DateTime) END AS FechaAlta_As_DateTime FROM Tutors
```

Answer (score -2):

First get datetime2 and datetime in the same `datetime` format. Assuming they both are of `date datatype` and you are working on `Oracle`

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME2,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')) = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:sql-server], not [tag:oracle]. Error message is also distinctly SQL Server "flavoured".