# SQL SERVER ERROR: "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." (informix to sql server)

Tags: sql-server, informix, linked-server, openquery, datetime2

I have a sql server linked server to access an informix database, and I'm using openquery to run the queries, and then insert the results in a sql server table.

The problem is that when I run a code like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
( date, comments, user )
SELECT f.date
     , f.comments
     , f.user
  FROM OPENQUERY( LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 
                  'select date
                        , description as comments
                        , user_name as user
                     from tsperson' 
                 ) AS f
```

I got this error:

> "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

I've already tried to cast but that doesn't worked.

I've searched here and in Google for some answer but not founded.

So, can someone help me?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386360/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-o

Comment: Paddy answer was more explained and has very clear alternatives to me to how to solve the problem. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the `date` field in your table that you are inserting into is using a `datetime` datatype.  You are receiving data in a `datetime2` format that is out of the range of a valid `datetime` type.

You may have to update the table so that `date` is a `datetime2` type, or filter the incoming data to remove dates that you cannot support.

---

`datetime` date rage: January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

`datetime2` date range: 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql